# Binding a Kendo cascading dropdown to a List property within a list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, frontend

I have two classes:

```
class Enterprise
{
    string EnterpriseCode {get; set;}
    string LocationCode {get; set;}
    List<FinYear> FinYears {get; set;}
}

class FinYear
{
    string FinancialYear {get; set;}
}
```

---

From my Controller, I am passing a strongly typed view of datatype List<Enterprise>

I have two Kendo dropdownlists in the HTML section of the view:

```
@model List<Enterprise>

@(Html.Kendo.DropDownList()
.Name("EnterpriseDDL)
.BindTo(Model)
.DataTextField("EnterpriseCode")
.DataValueField("Enterprise")
```

and

```
(Html.Kendo.DropDownList()
.Name("YearsDDL")
.cascadeFrom("EnterpriseDDL")
.BindTo(Model) //!!! not sure about this
.DataTextField("") //!!!
.DataValueField("") //!!!
```

**What should these three fields be so the DDL contains the list of fin years associated
   with an enterprise (as chosen in the previous dropdown)**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't cascade from this because there is no `Parent <-> Child` relationship. This means the `FinYear` has no `ParentID`. You need to change the dataSource of the second ComboBox manually or implement a connection.

[ComboBox.cascadeFrom](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/combobox#configuration-cascadeFrom)

> - The child combobox will listen to any changes of the parent's value.
> - If the parent does not have a value, then the child will be disabled.

[Cascading ComboBoxes](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/cascading)
[ComboBox / Cascading ComboBox Demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/combobox/cascadingcombobox)

Here's a [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/o11rvn4a/1/): - it's `JavaScript` but I think you can easily modify it for the extensions too.

**HTML**:

```
<div class="demo-section k-header">
    <p>
        <label for="categories">Enterprises:</label><input id="categories" style="width: 270px" />
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="products">FinYear:</label><input id="products" style="width: 270px" />
    </p>
</div>
```

**JavaScript**:

```
var enterpriseArray = [{
  EnterpriseCode: "abc",
  LocationCode: "123",
  FinYears: [ "2014", "2015" ]
},
{
  EnterpriseCode: "def",
  LocationCode: "456",
  FinYears: [ "2012", "2013" ]
}];

$(document).ready(function() {
    var categories = $("#categories").kendoComboBox({                      
        placeholder: "Select Enterprise Code...",
        dataTextField: "EnterpriseCode",
        dataValueField: "EnterpriseCode",
        dataSource: enterpriseArray,
        change: function(e) {
          //debugger;
          products.dataSource.data(e.sender.dataItem().FinYears);
        }
    }).data("kendoComboBox");

    var products = $("#products").kendoComboBox({                       
        placeholder: "Select FinYear...",
        //dataTextField: "",
        //dataValueField: "",
    }).data("kendoComboBox");

});
```

Comment: Can the datasource of the of the 'categories' comboBox be the Model passed to the View? If possible, how do you do so? I get javascript errors when I try.
Also, what is the difference between comboBox and Dropdown (in Kendo) since you get the results in your demonstration.

Comment: 1 - yes, it can be, if it couldn't mvc were useless :-) 2 - I think this is too broad to be answered here. 3 - The only difference between them is: _The combobox allows the user to pick a value from a predefined set or input a custom one. The dropdownlist only allows picking one of the predefined values._

Comment: Is it possible for you to edit your above answer so that the datasource is the Model?

Comment: @NehaAgrawal this would be about model binding and is very broad. I don't think I can explain it in few words. Depending on which approach you use (javascript or razor extensions) you'll either need a json for the data source or a model and based on this you need to accordignly implement your ActionResult to return the data in the desired format.

Comment: thanks. your solution helped me figure out the write answer..eventually :)